# Oracle SQL insert NUMBER into table column is rounding off the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm inserting data into the table column whose type is NUMBER(5,2)  but when i insert the record it is rounding off the number. I want the number to be rounded off to 2 places after decimal only i.e. if 39.999 then it must enter 39.99 and not 40 like it is happening now

```
SHAREHOLDING_PER            NUMBER(5,2)     NOT NULL
```

below is my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO XX_DETAILS_TBL (SHAREHOLDING_PER) VALUES (39.999);
```

it is returning data as below
[image]

i want it to enter the data as is i.e. upto 2 decimal places after decimal point. i want in above case to store 39.99 in table column

Comment: For what it's worth, the usual term for that is not rounding but truncating (also called floor in some languages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Oracle rounds the number to the nearest value that can fit in the specified precision and scale. In your case, 39.999 gets rounded to 40.00 because that's the nearest number that fits the `NUMBER(5,2)` format (i.e. up to 5 digits in total, with only **2** of those digits after the decimal point).

So everything here worked as expected: Oracle cannot store 3 digits after the decimal point (bacause of `2` in `Number(5,2)`, so it tried to round them to the nearest value it could store.

If you need those numbers to be trimmed (or, in other words, 'rounded down'), you will unfortunately have to do it yourself.
One way to do that would be using `TRUNC` function:

```sql
INSERT INTO XX_DETAILS_TBL (SHAREHOLDING_PER) VALUES (TRUNC(39.999, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current column definition `NUMBER(5,2)` will store 5 digits of which 2 are decimal digits and the remaining 3 are integer digits.

If you want to store 3 integer and 3 decimal places then use `NUMBER(6,3)` in the table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE XX_DETAILS_TBL(
  SHAREHOLDING_PER NUMBER(6,3) NOT NULL
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO XX_DETAILS_TBL (SHAREHOLDING_PER) VALUES (39.999);
```

Can store `39.999` with all the decimal digits.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1-9R-Piq)

---

If you are just using `NUMBER(5,2)` then the database will respect how you defined the table and can only store 2 decimal digits and, if you are giving numbers with a greater precision then it will round the number to the precision you defined for the table so `39.999` will be rounded to `40.00` which will be stored as `40` (because `40` and `40.00` are exactly the same value).

If you want to truncate the value from `39.999` to `39.99` then you will have to explicitly specify that the value should be truncated using `TRUNC(39.999)` in the `INSERT` statement.